# Are HMACs based on hashes with larger bit-lengths also more secure?

Tags: authentication, provable-security, hmac

When doing encrypt-then-mac, I can choose to use a [hmac](/questions/tagged/hmac) as the MAC. For example, I could use a hash like SHA-256 or SHA-512 (by using it as a keyed hash) to create that HMAC.

Does it increase security when choosing a hash with a larger bit-size? Is a HMAC based on SHA-256 weaker than a SHA-512, or doesn’t it really matter because both are cryptographically secure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HMAC-SHA-256 is sufficient for up to 256 bit security. Confer e.g. [NIST SP 800-107](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-107-rev1/sp800-107-rev1.pdf). This recommendation is based on the premise that collision attacks are infeasible against common uses of HMAC, and that you consequently only have to worry about primary pre-image attacks that attempt to recover the secret key (and use this for forging subsequent messages).

SHA-256 has 256 bit security against primary pre-image attacks. This is sufficient for all practical purposes.

Comment: This is also why HMAC-SHA1 is still commonly used, even though the SHA-1 algorithm shouldn't be used anymore for e.g. signature generation. It is unlikely that SHA-1 will be vulnerable to first pre-image attacks, and the 160 bit output size offers enough security. Of course, if possible, you should still move to SHA-2 or SHA-3 (when the latter has been standardized).